# How to deserialize array with null values?

Tags: c#, deserialization, system.text.json

I need to deserialize this json:

`[null]`

to a `List<JsonNode>`

unfortunately instead, I get this exception:

```
System.Text.Json.JsonException: 'The JSON value could not be converted to System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode. Path: $[0] | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 5.'
```

How to deserialize to a list with a single null value in it?

This code

```
var toJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize<List<JsonNode>>(new List<JsonNode>{ null });
```

Gives this json:

`[null]`

But this code

```
var fromJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonNode>>("[null]");
```

Throws above

Comment: JsonNode is abstract.

Comment: Tye to deserialize into `var fromJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonElement>>("[null]");` it should work.

Comment: Looks like this was fixed in .NET 8 preview 5, see https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/85463.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update** this is a bug in System.Text.Json which has been fixed in **.NET 8** as of [Preview 5](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/commit/c77d916fc383469d89c510028ed4115d16a85519).  See:

- [Deserialising null to JsonNode in nested structures fails in System.Text.Json #85172](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/85172).
- [fix JsonNode deserialising from null #85463](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/pull/85463).
- [System.Text.Json: Exception thrown trying to deserialize a `List<JsonNode>` or `JsonNode []` from a JSON array containing a null entry, e.g. [null]. #92902](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/92902)/

A failing .NET 7 demo fiddle was created [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3SXnDG).

**As a workaround** in earlier versions, you could create a custom converter for `List<JsonNode>` like the following:

```
public class JsonNodeListConverter : JsonConverter<IEnumerable<JsonNode?>>
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => 
        objectType == typeof(List<JsonNode>) || objectType == typeof(IReadOnlyList<JsonNode>) || objectType == typeof(IReadOnlyCollection<JsonNode>) || objectType == typeof(JsonNode [])  || objectType == typeof(IEnumerable<JsonNode>);
    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, IEnumerable<JsonNode?> value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        writer.WriteStartArray();
        foreach (var node in value)
            JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, node, options);
        writer.WriteEndArray();
    }
    
    public override IEnumerable<JsonNode?> Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) 
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonTokenType.StartArray)
            throw new JsonException();
        var list = new List<JsonNode?>();
        while (reader.ReadAndAssert().TokenType != JsonTokenType.EndArray)
        {
            list.Add(JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>(ref reader, options));
        }
        return typeToConvert.IsArray ? list.ToArray() : list;
    }
}

public static class JsonExtensions
{
    public static ref Utf8JsonReader ReadAndAssert(ref this Utf8JsonReader reader) { if (!reader.Read()) { throw new JsonException(); } return ref reader; }
}
```

Then use as follows:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    Converters = { new JsonNodeListConverter() },
};
JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonNode>>("""[null]""", options)
```

And you will be able to deserialize lists and arrays of `JsonNode` that include null values.

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ysr2pW).

**Alternatively**, you could deserialize to an intermediate `IEnumerable<object>` with the option [`JsonSerializerOptions.UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonunknowntypehandling) and your non-null JSON array values will be deserialized as `JsonNode` subtypes:

```
var options = new JsonSerializerOptions
{
    UnknownTypeHandling = JsonUnknownTypeHandling.JsonNode,
};
var list = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<object>>("""[null, [null], 1, {}, "a"]""",
                                                           options)
     ?.Cast<JsonNode?>().ToList();
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/BqbdSj).

Answer (score 0):

JsonNode is an abstract class and a base class for JsonObject and for a JsonArray. But JsonArray and JsonObject[] are completely different. I don't know why do you need it but you can not deserialize a json string directly. But there is a trick,  you can use LINQ Select and ToList

```
string toJson = JsonSerializer.Serialize(new List<JsonNode>{ null });

List<JsonNode> fromJson = JsonArray.Parse(toJson)
                            .AsArray()
                            .Select(v => v.Deserialize<JsonNode>())
                            .ToList();
//or

List<JsonNode> fromJson = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonElement>>(toJson)
                                           .Select(v => v.Deserialize<JsonNode>() )
                                           .ToList();
```

Comment: *JsonNode is an abstract class, so you can not deserialize a json string directly.* -- actually you can, for instance `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>("[null]")` works just fine, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/mzUyKm.  While abstract, `JsonNode` is a built-in type so System.Text.Json knows (except in OP's case) to use the correct concrete type depending on the actual JSON.  (Json.NET functions similarly in that you can deserialize to a `JToken` and the correct concrete subclass will get created.)

Comment: @dbc Did you read the question?  That is the  problem that  List<JsonNode> node = System.Text.Json. JsonSerializer.Deserialize<JsonNode>(toJson)"[null]") throws the exception. OP needs a LIST not just a JsonNode. There is a big difference between JsonArray and List<JsonObject>.  List<JsonNode> maybe equal List<JsonArray> or List<JsonObject>

Comment: I did indeed read the question. And both your code samples works fine and deserialize `"[null]"` to a `List<JsonNode>`. But your explanation that *JsonNode is an abstract class, so you can not deserialize a json string directly.* is not quite right.  You can deserialize to `JsonNode` (or `List<JsonNode>`) in many cases despite the fact that it is abstract.  For instance `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<JsonNode>>("""[1,"a"]""");` works fine. `"[null]"` fails not because `JsonNode` is abstract, but because there is a bug in System.Text.Json deserializing `null` to `JsonNode` inside collections.

Comment: @dbc I am sorry but I hate  long explanations and never read any explanations to the answers, only the code. I think a real programmer doesn't need any code explanations. If a person needs explanations he should select another profession. But just because of my respect to you, I updated my answer.